# Java Hibernate Duplicate Entry for objects related to existing objects

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Class : Playlist has many songs

```
@OneToMany
private List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
```

Songs exist in the database already.
I'm trying to create a playlist that has a list of tracks without hibernate trying to create duplicate tracks

```
Playlist playlist = new Playlist(playlistName);
PersistenceUtil.persist(playlist);
playlist.addTracks(tracks);
PersistenceUtil.merge(playlist);
```

Error message :

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '4' for key 'tracks_id'
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1269)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:955)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.addToBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1168)
... 14 more
```

Comment: what is the content of tracks? Are you sure that you don't have duplicate id for some reason?

Comment: why are you  save and later updating? try persist only after addTracks method